# Saving to redux store by key, nested state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

**Chat application:**

I would like to save different ChatMessages arrays per conversation id.

I've imagined the state would look something like this:

```
state {
  messages: {
   isRequesting: false,
   messageByConversationId: {
    "23523534543": [messages],
    "64634523453": [messages],
   }
 }
}
```

But I can't seem to save a nested state, is it possible?

My code: (That does not run because of this line: chatMessage[conversationId]: payload.chatMessages)

```
export const loadChatMessagesSuccess: Reducer<ImmutableChatMessagesState> =
  (state: ImmutableChatMessagesState, {payload}: AnyAction & { payload?: LoadChatMessagesSuccessParams }) =>
    payload ? {...state, requesting: false, chatMessage[conversationId]: payload.chatMessages}
      : state;
```

Comment: Question not clear :(

Comment: @ShankarShastri is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question. But you could do the following to add loaded messages to the `messageByConversationId` object while keeping other loaded messages.

NB. This assumes you have somehow get `conversationId` as a variable. For example you could make it to be a part of `payload`

```
export const loadChatMessagesSuccess: Reducer<ImmutableChatMessagesState> = (
  state: ImmutableChatMessagesState,
  { payload }: AnyAction & { payload?: LoadChatMessagesSuccessParams }
) =>
  payload
    ? {
        ...state,
        requesting: false,
        messageByConversationId: {
          ...state.messageByConversationId,
          [payload.conversationId]: payload.chatMessages
        }
      }
    : state;
```